# Notations on Craig-Wayne's 1993 paper on PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

I'm currently reading [Craig-Wayne's *Newton's Method and Periodic Solutions of Nonlinear Wave Equations*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d646/ce1244e0004954d0d3f1ece4c55f1cc57cae.pdf). My background includes undergraduate functional analysis and PDE, and there are some notations which I would like to clarify.

On page 8, $(2.8)$ introduces the equation $W(U) + V(\Omega)U = 0$, and down the page, it explains that $W : \mathcal{H}_\sigma \to \mathcal{H}_{\sigma - \gamma}$ is a real analytic map for every $0 < \gamma \leq \sigma < \bar{\sigma}$, but did not define $W(U)$ explicitly, and no other information about $W(U)$ is provided prior to page 9.

1. I would like to know if $W(U)$ is a notation for some commonly defined map?
2. $V(\Omega)$ is explicitly defined in $(2.9)$. Am I right to say that $V(\Omega)U$ is the notation for $V(\Omega)(U)$, i.e. $V(\Omega)$ with the input $U$?

It also then says that $W(0) = 0$ and $D_UW(0) = 0$. On the next page, they introduced the linearised operator $H(U) = V(\Omega) + DW(U)$.

3. I would also like to clarify the meaning of $D_UW$ and $DW(U)$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just before (2.8): "The lattice problem arises by expanding solutions $u(x,t)$ of (2.1) in eigenfunction-Fourier series". By (2.1), the coefficients $U(i,j)$ in this expansion satisfy an equation. They say this equation can be written in the form (2.8). The definition of $W(U)$ should follow from the equation and the definition of $V(\Omega)$.

Comment: @RicardoBuring so we're saying that there exists $W(U)$ (dependent on each $U(i,j)$) such that $W(U) + V(\Omega)U = 0$. In that case, what's the domain for $W(U)$? I.e. we usually say "there exists a linear transformation $T$...", "there exists a group homomorphism $\phi$...", and in the case what is the "there exists a <?> $W(U)$..."?